# Angular Load view at once - not gradually

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dictionary, hide

I have a map where each value is an array which the component trans-p displays
The problem is that when each component finishes to load then it's displayed.
Meaning user sees one table in view, then the other. etc.
While I need them to  be loaded all at once
Is there a way to do this?

The code:

```
<div *ngFor='let arr of pMap |keyvalue;let i=index'>
<div>
{{titles[arr.key]}}
<tran-p [pArr]='arr.value' [statusP]='arr.key'></tran-p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are all the arrays in the pMap variable? og do you have multiple pMap variables. One for each table?

Comment: I don't think I understand how your data is structured from the code above compared to what you want to achieve...

Comment: Then how about creating a boolean variable that toggles alle components when they are ready?

Comment: what should be the condition for knowing when they are loaded?
can you give example?

Comment: the data I believe is being loaded from somewhere. When it is all loaded you could enable the variable to display the list.

If there is a lot of data you might want to shrink it or make pages, since angular is not that great at displaying a ton of data at once. Then there might be some delay between the first component being displayed and the last.